# If I don't define a constructor for a subclass, can I use the constructor of the superclass directly?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, constructor

Are constructors inherited or do they belong to the class they are defined in? I only have seen examples with constructors of subclasses which call superclass' constructors. This is my current code, which can give some hint about what's going on. (I will change the code according to your replies. If I can use the constructor of the superclass, I won't define a constructor for each subclass and call superclass' constructor from each.

```
abstract class view
{
 public $vieverid;

 function __construct($viewerid) {
  $this->viewer = $viewerid;
 }
}
class viewactor extends view{

 function __construct($viewerid) {
  $this->viewerid = $viewerid;
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`parent::__construct(params);` use for calling superclass constructor

> PHP4
>
> PHP doesn't call constructors of the base class automatically from a
>   constructor of a derived class. It is your responsibility to propagate
>   the call to constructors upstream where appropriate.
>
> PHP5
>
> PHP doesn't call constructors of the base class if new constructor defined. 
>   If you define a constructor for derived class
>   It is your responsibility to propagate
>   the call to constructors upstream where appropriate.
>   parent::__construct(params)

Constructors

```
abstract class view
{
 public $vieverid;

 function __construct($viewerid) {
  $this->vieverid= $viewerid;
 }
}

class viewactor extends view{

 function __construct($viewerid) {
   parent::__construct($viewerid);
   // Extra code if you want
 }
}

class viewactor_construct extends view{
    // Works in PHP5
}
```

Comment: on this thread, moe said "According to my understanding, PHP doesn't auto-call parent's constructor if child constructor is defined. Otherwise it does." do you agree with this?

Comment: I agree. If you don't define a constructor, parents constructor will be called in PHP5

Answer (score 4):

According to my understanding, PHP doesn't auto-call parent's constructor if child constructor is defined. Otherwise it does.

In child constructor you have to call parent's constructor manually.

```
abstract class view
{
 public $vieverid;

 function __construct($viewerid) {
  $this->viewer = $viewerid;
 }
}
class viewactor extends view{

 function __construct($viewerid) {
  parent::__construct($viewerid); // manual call
  // do your stuff here...
  $this->viewerid = $viewerid;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Parent constructors are not called implicitly if the child class defines a constructor. In order to run a parent constructor, a call to parent::__construct() within the child constructor is required.

[See here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)

Comment: they why do you think all examples have such code?
class viewactor extends view{

 function __construct($viewerid) {
   parent::__construct($viewerid);
 }